# Skimage.filter not importing into conda virtual environment on mac

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, scikit-image

I'm trying to get skimage.filter.gaussian to import properly.

I've created numerous conda environments and added all necessary packages and dependencies for my project to run. I've tried building environements with python 2.7, python 3.6 & python 3.5 and just can't manage to get the filter libraries into the project and get hit by:

```
from skimage.filter import gaussian
ImportError: cannot import name gaussian
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing all virtual environments and creating from scratch ensuring all [Scikit-image 0.13.0 dependencies](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikit-image) are met ('requires distributions').

Currently running gaussian successfully with Python 2.7 and Opencv 2.4.11 (conda install -c menpo opencv) in an Anaconda Environment.

[image: conda list -n virtualEnv]